# Is it safe to use ucontext_t on linux arm64?

Tags: linux, arm, posix, arm64

ucontext_t has been removed from POSIX, but is still there in glibc.

Is it safe to use it on a linux-arm64 if I don't care about interoperability? Any gotchas? (floating point registers or anything else I should be worry of?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be perfectly safe to use.  Just because `ucontext.h` was removed from POSIX.1-2017/SUSv7 does not mean that `glibc` no longer supports the functionality.

This particular header was removed in the latest version of the standard since IEEE Std 1003.1-2001/Cor 2-2004, item XBD/TC2/D6/28 was applied in the previous version of the standard, updating the `getcontext`, `makecontext`, `setcontext`, and `swapcontext` functions to be obsolescent, and thus the header was also defacto obsolescent.